# How to hide new created user in /etc/passwd in Linux?

Tags: password

I have created new user named "testuser" in linux system. After that i used "cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd" cammand to show user list in system.

Now I can see all users including new created user "testuser".

I want to hide "testuser" from /etc/passwd .

Is there any solution for this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. Why do you want to hide the testuser? To prevent people to find out who can log in on the system? Making `/etc/passwd` inaccessible will not achieve that goal. You seem to have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: if we remove read permission to other group so it can't read /etc/passwd file.I want to keep read permission but hide new user  "testuser" from the list.

Comment: Please update your question with the additional information, don't put it in the comments. In particular, make clear whether it is your goal to not have `testuser` in `/etc/passwd` at all, and if so _why_ you want that. The point is that since `/etc/passwd` **defines** the local users of the system, there is absolutely no way that `testuser` is not in that file and still a local user. However, I expect that you want to remove `testuser` from `/etc/passwd` for _some reason_. Knowing that reason will help people to come up with a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you cannot do that , the local user should be registered in `/etc/passwd` , there is some tips like :

1. creating user accounts with uid < 1000  so GUI tools ignore it  .
2. creating shell users so it will not be seen at login screen .

But at `cli` level they will catch you !